# Query executed but returns blank screen

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, geometry, query

I have two tables, flickr_edin and routea
flickr_edin contains columns id, date_taken, user and geom.
routea consists of a single entry of a line string under the geom column.

Use flickr table to show the popularity of each route according to how many photos have been taken along the route within a 25m buffer. You should normalise this by route length (i.e. photos per metre).

I have used this query to solve the problem but I get a blank screen and it shows the query is executed. I believe there might be something wrong with the way I have framed my query or maybe ST_TOUCHES is the wrong way to go.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/ST_LENGTH(routea.geom) as Count FROM flickr_edin, routea
WHERE ST_TOUCHES(flickr_edin.geom, ST_BUFFER(routea.geom, 25))
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

ST_TOUCHES Returns TRUE if the only points in common between g1 and g2 lie in the union of the boundaries of g1 and g2.

In other words, you're seeing if your buffered points share an edge with the linestring. You want [ST_DWITHIN](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). I don't have your data but try:

SELECT COUNT(*)/ST_LENGTH(routea.geom)::float as Count FROM flickr_edin, routea
WHERE ST_DWITHIN(flickr_edin.geom, routea.geom 25)
ORDER BY Count DESC;