# Max of count does not give me the result I need

Tags: qgis, postgresql, point, geometry, query

I need to display the max of count for this query.
I tried a nested way but I could not get it to return the centroid of that cell.

Here flickr_edin table data consists of points
and grid100m table data contains polygons

```
SELECT Max(P_density)
FROM(COUNT(a.geom) as P_density,ST_ASTEXT(ST_CENTROID(b.geom)) 
FROM flickr_edin a JOIN grid100m b ON ST_WITHIN(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY b.geom
ORDER BY P_density DESC) A;
```

How should I frame it instead so I can get the centroid point returned as well?

Comment: What are you trying to get? Max of count doesn't make a whole lot of sense as count() gives you the sum of the features you're counting. Can you write out what you expect to get from your query?

Comment: If you just want the highest value returned from the count, try LIMIT 1 at the end. You can also subquery/CTE and select MAX(P_density) from the initial query. BTW if you want that field to have a capital letter, you need to wrap it in quotation marks.

Comment: @Encomium Hi, yes I wasn't able to get the sub query  right,  I did exactly that but I don't know where to place the ST_ASTEXT(ST_CENTROID(b.geom)) part of my query when I make the sub query for it because I want that returned too.

Comment: Ok, will write it out.

Comment: @Encomium Thanks a lot. Do you mind checking out this previous query too? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417022/query-executed-but-returns-blank-screen Honestly, Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Max on geom_centroid as well. See how this:

```
SELECT 
Max(p_density) as max_density,
Max(geom_centroid) as geom_centroid 
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(a.geom) as p_density,ST_ASTEXT(ST_CENTROID(b.geom)) as geom_centroid 
FROM flickr_edin a JOIN grid100m b ON ST_WITHIN(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY b.geom
) A;
```

Compares to this:

```
SELECT 
Max(p_density) as max_density
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(a.geom) as p_density,ST_ASTEXT(ST_CENTROID(b.geom)) as geom_centroid 
FROM flickr_edin a JOIN grid100m b ON ST_WITHIN(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY b.geom
) A;
```

Do you get the same max density from both queries?

Comment: Really appreciate the help. Do you mind checking out this previous query too? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417022/query-executed-but-returns-blank-screen

Comment: Sure. I think I see the issue

Comment: you're a life saver thank you !

Comment: Go have a look now. I didn't recreate your data so I'm not sure if the query returns what you're looking for.